# ASIHTTPRequest timeout with AnyConnect

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, asihttprequest, vpn

In my app I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to get information from a server. That works fine as long as I am using the company's wireless.

However, I need to connect now from outside of the network, by using Cisco AnyConnect. On the PC, the connection to the server via VPN works but I cannot reach the server through the app. I always get timeout although I have increased the timeout interval to 60 seconds (which is already too much).

Is there something special that I need to change in the code when I use AnyConnect? Right now, it does not automatically detect the proxy, I get `(null)` as `proxyHost` and `0` as `proxyPort`.

Comment: Is the URL a local address?

Comment: It is only locally reachable. The URL looks like that: `http://<some-words>.local:<port>/<remaining-part-of-url>`.

Comment: Have you tried connect on demand from the advanced screen?

Comment: Do you mean the `ASIAuthenticationDialog`? I was not able to use it. I have synchronous requests but even after commenting out the check in `ASIHTTPRequest`, the dialog is not shown. My app doesn't known that I am using proxy. I don't know how to detect that and to put it then in the request.

Comment: No I'm talking about the AnyConnect app. You are using the app to establish a vpn connection, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using AnyConnect to establish the connection. I just checked the connection on demand. I set my network to be used on demand but my app doesn't know that it needs VPN and by far not that the request should go through AnyConnect. So basically, for my app, nothing changes, I cannot establish the connection to the server.

Comment: Your app doesn't need to know it's using a VPN. Simply accessing a local ip address will automatically use the VPN. Don't try to use a proxy.

Comment: Then it seems that I don't know how to configure AnyConnect. Right now, I have my network, connect on demand is on, and in the domain list, under "connect if needed", I have the following part of the address from above: `<some-words>.local:<port>`. I tried also without the port but both don't work. In the app, I have nothing about VPN, just the code that I am using within the company's wireless.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a DNS issue. Have you tried the ip address instead?

Comment: I just put all possible combinations of the address under "always connect". The result is that now I get another error. On the iPhone I get alert with "VPN Connection: The VPN connection requires an application to start up." The error in XCode is "A connection failure occurred [...] The operation couldn’t be completed. Network is down."

Comment: I just found out that for this connection on demand I need a certificate which, unfortunately, I don't have. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Try disabling the on demand just use an ip address. It still just sounds like a dns issue. Not sure if that doesn't work.

Comment: How to use the IP address? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you a lot for the help, @MarkM. Using the IP solved my problem. I just replaced `http://<some-words>.local:<port>/<remaining-part-of-url>` by `http://<IP>:<port>/<remaining-part-of-url>` and it works.